# Hibernate query to get all distinct rows based on a where condition

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, hql

I have a POJO named `SiteProperty` as follows:

```
public class SiteProperty
{
    private int sitePropertyId;
    private int siteId;
    private String  key;
    private String  value;
    private String  type;
}
```

Is there any way to get all the distinct values of `value` for the given `siteId`? Also the same `value` might be there with `siteId` 0. So basically the query should get all the rows for `siteId` 0 and then if any of the `value` is present for the specified `siteId` then that row has to be returned insted of the one for `siteId` 0.

I use `PostgreSQL` database for my application.

I am very new to this. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Basicaly I have many `value` and `key` pairs in the table for `siteId` 0, and this are the default values. There can be a different `value` for the same `key` for some values of `siteId`. If for a `siteId` there is an `value` corresponding to a `key` it has to be returned, else the `value` corresponding to the same `key` for `siteId` 0 should be returned. And the return data should be a list of type `SiteProperty`

I have tried a sample SQL query in the pgAdmin tool to test the result I get:

```
select * from site_property where site_key IN (SELECT DISTINCT site_key FROM site_property where site_id = 0 or site_id = 3) and site_id = 0 or site_id = 3;
```

This query is just a trial, the result gives me a combination of data with both the `siteId`.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What's the concrete problem?

Comment: @JBNizet, I have updated my problem in the question

Comment: I have understood your requirements. But what problem did you face when trying to implement the solution? Where is your attempt?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `Projection` to a `Criteria` (which is a builder-class for a query):

```
Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCritiera(SiteProperty.class);
criteria.add(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("value")));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("siteId", 0));
List<String> resultList = critiera.list();
```

Comment: Why use criteria for such a static query rather than HQL? Also, your query won't return a List<SiteProperty>.

Comment: I don't like HQL that much. You could easily do a typo or construct something too long (and wrong). My prefer goes to the Criteria API.

Comment: You could almost as easily write something wrong with Criteria, and you will always write something much less readable than `select distinct sp.value from SiteProperty sp where sp.siteId = :siteId`. Automated tests are necessary for both anyway. Also, SiteProperty_.value is a SingularAttribute, and Projections.property() expects a String. You're using the standard JPA metadata classes, used by the standard JPA criteria API, with the old, proprietary, Hibernate API.